# How to show Qty left in Magento 2 Listing page?

Tags: magento2, product, stock, quantity

I need to show Qty left message with qty of product in product detail page with below condition.
If the available stock is less than 'Notify for Quantity Below' parameter of each product.

And can we show same message in product detail page More Information tab?

I have set Only X left Threshold as 15 in **Store -> Configuration->Catalog->Inventory**

I need to show That Qty left message message only if it is less than this value.

How this can be checked and show.

Please anyone suggest me in this?

Comment: How do you show configurable products qty?

Comment: Right now we are not using any configurable products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a block class to your custom module named Vendor_Module to below path:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product.php

and add the below content to it:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_stockInterface;
    protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockInterface,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ){
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_stockInterface = $stockInterface;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getStockMessage($productId){
        $_product = $this->getProductById($productId);
        $_stock = $this->getStock($_product);
        if($_stock <= $this->getThresoldQty()){
            return __('Only %1 left', $_stock);
        }
        return '';
    }

    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    }

    public function getStock($_product)
    {
        return $this->_stockInterface->getStockQty($_product->getId(), $_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
    }

    public function getThresoldQty(){
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('cataloginventory/options/stock_threshold_qty', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
}
```

Now add the below code to top of your **list.phtml**

```
$blockObj = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Product');
```

Then call the below block inside your foreach loop:

```
<?php echo $blockObj->getStockMessage($_product->getId()); ?>
```

You can use the thing in your product details page.

Comment: this code will applicable to all products, but i need to check with condition and show, if stock is less than 'Notify for Quantity Below' parameter of the product and I need to show it More Information Tab of the product page.

Comment: This will give you the quantity now you can put your condition and render accordingly

Comment: Yes i got that code, but checking condition is only i am looking for, how can i check the condition for threshold qty?

Comment: ok wait I am updating my code

Comment: ok, please update me the code

Comment: Check my updated code.

Comment: okay, can i create this block file in any of the custom module is it?

Comment: Yes if you create this block in other custom module then you need to change the Vendor and Module name everywhere of my code.

Comment: i am getting Only 0 left as result, even if i have quantity of 3, but your code for block is working fine. why stock is taking as 0 for all products? I have qty for those products

Comment: Are you sure? I think you need to reindex. As it working fine from my end. Did you pass product id as I have passed it to that function?

Comment: yes i am passing productid to your method, inside for each like this $_product->getId(), do i need to use StockRegistryInterface instead of StockItemRepository?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83009/discussion-between-sukumar-gorai-and-jafar-pinjar).